# Union and memory management

Tags: c, unions, bit

I was at an interview and the following code was given to me:-

```
union mix
{
    int i;
    char c[2];
};

int main()
{
    union mix key;
    key.i=512;
    printf("\n %d,%d,%d",key.i,key.c[0],key.c[1]);
    return 0;   
}
```

and when I came home and ran it on the system I got the **output:- 512,0,2**.

Can anyone explain it to me **how it works or why is c[1]=2**?

Edit :- all I know is that it is related to bit storage in the memory.

Comment: I'm sorry, if you are in an interview for a C developer and you don't know how data types and memory works... Just think how the data is stored in memory and you should understand it.

Comment: Sami it was not an interview for c devlooer it was an interview for Java where the HRs kindaa decided to test C skills of the developers :D

Comment: @NeoR: Well, that's not nice ...

Comment: Yeah well thats life simply unfair

Comment: Thanks for the alternate link @alk but I guess the endianess by Moses explains it to me a little better.

Comment: @NeoR just fyi, the output you observed means your machine is a little endian.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a union, meaning `i` and `c` occupy the same memory.
512 is 0x200, meaning first byte is zero, second is 2 (each byte takes two hex digits).
This of course depends on the endianness of your CPU.

Comment: can you explain endian?

Comment: @NeoR - I could, but wikipedia could do it better: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness . It's basically the order which bytes are arranged, your example is with little endian.

Comment: I think that it is worth pointing out that OPs code prints `key.c[0] = 0`, and `key.c[1] = 2` as _decimal_ values, and that these are the _decimal_ representations of the specified bytes. It is coincidence that `0x00` = `0`, and `0x02` = `2`. In other words, if `key.i = 350`, the results would not look like the hex representation.